# TextBox Undo/Redo commands

Tags: winforms

The WinForms TextBox has an 'Undo' command but has not a 'Redo' command - Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the native Windows Edit control, the base for TextBox, has WM_UNDO but not WM_REDO.  It has lots of quirks, dating back from Windows 1.0 and a gazillion app compat patches.