# Any TextBox control for WinForms with multi level undo feature?

Tags: c#, winforms, undo-redo

I've searched half a day, and found none.

Do you happen to know there's one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Its not built in but you can implement your own
Take look to this post in stack over flow [C#: How to implement good and efficient undo/redo functionaly for a TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597792/c-how-to-implement-good-and-efficient-undo-redo-functionaly-for-a-textbox)

Answer (score 0):

you can implement custom undo feature in textbox ....

you can  handle the TextChanged event and just push the textbox contents onto a stack each time it changes, then pop and refresh the TextBox every time the user hits Ctrl-Z.....

Comment: Do you mean you will have a universal undo for the whole window?

Comment: No, I just mean the single textbox.