# (C# Form) Can't get undo button to actually work

Tags: c#, winforms

So I'm working on a text editor, using a menu strip as the main control area for everything. In my Edit tab I have an Undo button that is meant to undo the last word typed.

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
     Stack<string> undoList = new Stack<string>();

     private void txtMain_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hasSaved = false;
        txtMain = (RichTextBox)sender;
        undoList.Push(txtMain.Text);
    }

    private void tsUndo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            undoList.Pop();           
    }
}
```

When I click the undo it doesn't affect anything. I'm quite new to programming so I can't see the issue. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: You are just removing an element from the array. You don't tell to the button to do something.

Comment: That would make sense, do you know what code I should use to actually make the button do what I want?

Comment: Perhaps the define of "what I want" term can give us a clue for better code suggestion. Other than this the `sender` parameter is a reference to your button.

Comment: `txtMain.Text = undoList.Pop();` ? All `.Pop()` does is remove the item from `undoList` and return it to you. C# isn't psychic, I'm afraid.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used Stacks before so I didn't realise this before. So what I'm trying to do is have the undo button remove the last word typed from the textbox. As far as I understand, the stack is simply storing the states of the textbox. Im not sure how to then remove the last type word.

Comment: TextChanged is the wrong event to hook into - you are going to cache each letter as an UnDo item with no way to tell which ones go together to make a word/sentence/entry/unit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement good and efficient undo/redo functionality for a TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597792/how-to-implement-good-and-efficient-undo-redo-functionality-for-a-textbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will get few lines of your question and explain it to you:

```
Stack<string> undoList = new Stack<string>(); //Creates new EMPTY Stack
undoList.Push(txtMain.Text); //Add object to the top of the Stack
undoList.Pop(); //Removes object that is on top of the Stack
```

So now you have `TextBox` and when you type something `textbox.Text` property changes on it's own (not you affecting it). Then you created `event` that will "also" besides changing `text` property `Push()` old text to your `Stack` on the top.

Now after text change you "have" (you do not have i will explain it later) your string on top of `stack` and inside your `textbox`

Now when you press your `Undo` button you need to do two things.

- Set `textBox.Text` property to top object in stack
- Delete top object in stack

Currently what you were doing is just second thing:

```
undoList.Pop();
```

But what you forgot to type before that is:

```
textBox1.Text = undoList.Pop();
```

This way you will set `Text` property AND delete object on top of stack.

Now let's get back you my `you do not have i will explain it later`.

I have said this since `txtMain_TextChanged` is fired `AFTER` text is changed.

So when you get `txtMain.Text` after text is changed, you will get new value instead of old one.

Also you will update your old text every time you type 1 character.

Solution to this is to use `Enter` event

```
private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //it fires only when you enter textbox with mouse click/tab/etc
    //Here add your OLD VALUE to top  of stack
}
```